# Selecting a subset of entries, based on a relatedTo call

Tags: entries, relatedto

I have a question about relations... or maybe its also about making queries. First I want to select a set of data, and then I want to select a subset of that data, based on a relatedTo call.

If I first do this:

```
{% set caseEntries = craft.entries.section('case').relatedTo({ targetElement: creatorEntry, field: 'creator' }) %}
```

then, to get a sub-set of what I got before, do this:

```
{% set caseEntries = caseEntries.relatedTo('and', { targetElement: categoryEntry, field: 'caseCategories' }) %}
```

it seems as if the first relation is “forgotten” (note that it wont work if I dont include an “and” in the second related to call). Do I *have to* add the first relation in the second call? Feels like repeating myself... I want to avoid doing this:

```
{% set caseEntries = caseEntries.relatedTo('and', { targetElement: creatorEntry, field: 'creator' }, { targetElement: categoryEntry, field: 'caseCategories' }) %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Second `relatedTo` call overrides first one. Calling it again won't add more parameters to the query.

If you don't want to repeat yourself you can always do this:

```
{% set creatorRelated = { targetElement: creatorEntry, field: 'creator' } %}

{% set caseEntries = craft.entries.section('case').relatedTo(creatorRelated) %}

{% set caseEntries = caseEntries.relatedTo('and', creatorRelated, { targetElement: categoryEntry, field: 'caseCategories' }) %}
```